# "How long he been like that?"

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> A: My husband is in a coma.
>
> B: Oh. I'm sorry. I didn't know. **How long he been like that?**

I know the natural thing to say would probably be "How long has he been in a coma?" But if "coma" shouldn't be repeated, what would be natural instead? Would my suggestion work?

Comment: Absolutely not, unless you're trying to write in a specific dialect. You need to say "How long has he been like that?"

Comment: I suspect that the omission of _has_ was an error, and Bobobobo was asking about _been like that_. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: I somehow forgot "has" twice. But "been like that" is fine in the context?

Comment: Oh ok. Yes, it's fine in that context.

Answer (score 1):

> Oh. I'm sorry. I didn't know. How long he been like that?

As you suggest the word *has* has been omitted. This may be possible in some dialects and it is perfectly understandable.

> How long has he been in a coma?

Would be the longer form but your version replacing *in a coma* with *like that* would be correct and arguably what most people would use in conversation.